# How to filter image in python using PIL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

How to use python to filter an image based on colour?

Given a coloured image. I would like to turn it into an image that is black everywhere except for pixels that have colour close to the RGB colour (170,120,75).

How can I go about doing this efficiently?

Comment: For a start, you can have a look at [this tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html)

Comment: I did a nice, easy-to-follow example here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215020/2836621