# Change color in RGB images

Tags: python, numpy, colors, python-imaging-library, rgb

I have an image (I have it in both NumPy and PIL format), and I want to change where RGB values are `[0.4, 0.4, 0.4]` to `[0.54, 0.27, 0.07]`.

By doing this, I want to change the road color from gray to brown:

[image: road]

Comment: This answer was made for you! https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215020/2836621

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61808326/how-to-replace-all-rgb-values-in-an-numpy-image-arrray-based-on-an-target-pixel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to agree with Majid Shirazi regarding the [proposed solution by Quang Hong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59183744/11089932). Let's have a look at:

```py
idx = np.where(img == (0.4, 0.4, 0.4))
```

Then, `idx` is a 3-tuple containing each a `ndarray` for all `x`-coordinates, `y`-coordinates, and "channel"-coordinates. From NumPy's [indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html), I can't see a possibility to properly access/manipulate the values in `img` in the desired way using the proposed command. I can rather reproduce the exact error stated in the comment.

To get a proper [integer array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing), the `x`- and `y`-coordinates need to be extracted. The following code will show that. Alternatively, [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) might also be used. I added that as an add-on:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Some artificial image
img = np.swapaxes(np.tile(np.linspace(0, 1, 201), 603).reshape((201, 3, 201)), 1, 2)
cv2.imshow('before', img)

# Proposed solution
img1 = img.copy()
idx = np.where(img1 == (0.4, 0.4, 0.4))
try:
    img1[idx] = (0.54, 0.27, 0.27)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)

# Corrected solution for proper integer array indexing: Extract x and y coordinates
img1[idx[0], idx[1]] = (0.54, 0.27, 0.27)
cv2.imshow('after: corrected solution', img1)

# Alternative solution using boolean array indexing
img2 = img.copy()
img2[np.all(img2 == (0.4, 0.4, 0.4), axis=2), :] = (0.54, 0.27, 0.27)
cv2.imshow('after: alternative solution', img2)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Hope that helps and clarifies!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this numpy approach:

```
img[np.where(img == (0.4,0.4,0.4))] = (0.54,0.27,0.27)
```

Comment: thanks, but it gave me this error: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (13481,)

Answer (score 0):

The image you have loaded is represented as a three dimensional array. The shape of it should be `height, width, color channel`. Ie. if it only has RGB channels (some may have RGBA etc), the matrix properties would look like `height, width, 3`

The rest of it should be just as you treat a normal array. You can see it as this way:

`pixel = image[height][width][colorchannel]`

Quang Hoang's answer has a simple solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but it gave me this error: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (13481,)

Comment: Check the shape of your image through `image.shape`. It should have three elements as I described. What does it return?

Comment: what did you do to get that error? I just tested on a 1600x1200 rgb image. The shape gives me `(1600, 1200, 3)` and I could access the last pixel, `image[1599][1199][2]` without any problems

Comment: my image is 96x96 rgb image and I just typed : test[np.where(test ==(0.4,0.4,0.4))] = (0.54,0.27,0.27). then i got that error