# Converting numpy list of images to mp4 video

Tags: image, numpy, machine-learning, video, opencv, python

I have Numpy list of 1000 RGB images (1000, 96, 96, 3). I have used openCV to create a mp4 video out of these images. my road is brown and car is red but after I create the video they turned blue.
Could you please tell me how could I avoid this problem?

My code:

```
img_array = []
for img in brown_dataset:
    img_array.append(img)

size = (96,96)

out = cv2.VideoWriter('project_brown.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'),15, size)

for i in range(len(img_array)):
    out.write(img_array[i])
out.release()
```

Before video:

[image]

After video:

[image]

Comment: OpenCV uses BGR format by default, you can use `cv2.cvtColor` to flip it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change color in RGB images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59183691/change-color-in-rgb-images)

Comment: thanks, it completely worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments , OpenCV uses BGR format by default, where your input dataset is RGB.

Here is one way to fix it

```py
img_array = []
for img in brown_dataset:
    img_array.append(img)

size = (96,96)

out = cv2.VideoWriter('project_brown.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'),15, size)

for i in range(len(img_array)):
    rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(img_array[i], cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    out.write(rgb_img)
out.release()
```