# Detect brown field in a map and calculate its area

Tags: python, opencv

I have the following original image:
[image: Original_image]

I want to contour the dark brownfield and calculate its area.

Full code so far:

```
image=cv2.imread(file)

blurred_frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5, 5), 0)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blurred_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

brown_lo=np.array([10,0,0])
brown_hi=np.array([20,150,150])

mask=cv2.inRange(hsv,brown_lo,brown_hi)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for contour in contours:
        cv2.drawContours(image, contour, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

show(image)
show(mask)
```

But I do not get the filled field.

[image]

I have received a much better image after the comment. How do I calculate the area of the field now?

Comment: If you want to detect a colour, it is not an ideal strategy to immediately discard the colour and go to greyscale. Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215020/2836621

Comment: Try summing the pixels in the mask... that will tell you how many brown pixels you have. **Numpy** `np.sum()` is good for summing...

Comment: I need the whole area surrounded by red now. Summing pixels would only give me the outline, right?

Comment: Oh, I see. You could use a *"floodfill"* to fill the area and then count. And you can look at **OpenCV** `findContours()` or **scikit-image** `measure` https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html