# locating an image on screen with varying tolerance depending on level of color

Tags: python, image

hi im trying to create a script that will let me pinpoint
the location of an image on screen that is nearest to completion

[image]

so in the picture above image (2,1) should be picked first

Im clueless at the moment on what libraries to look upon as
pyautogui.locateOnScreen I believe only searches for exact match
can I ask for opinions on how to possibly implement this the easiest?

*btw the green filled ones should be discarded

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, but I think you are looking for the largest yellowish contour.... OpenCV `findContours()` springs to mind.

Comment: Ok thanks ill take a look at it, yes that is exactly what I want to look for the picture with the most yellow fills

Comment: If you change the numbers to suit your yellows (instead of the browns I was using) you can find all yellows like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215020/2836621

Comment: Thanks man appreciate, ill post it once I figured it out