# Search the coordinates of "most red" pixels in an image

Tags: python-3.x, image, search, rgb, pixel

Im currently trying to search pictures for the, what one could call, "most red" pixels and cannot use a fixed rgb value. so i tried to create a system of loops counting the g value up, then the b value and at last counting the r value down, to search for pixels with the highest r value, while maintaining low g and b values. the coordinates of the pixel/pixels should be saved to a tuple of arrays created with numpy. right now it doesnt find anything, even if i feed the program picture with the rgb value 255,0,0. do you have any opinions what could be wrong or how to search for the "most red" pixel coordinates of an image?(below "data[]" is an array with the rgb values of all pixels of the image which i got with PIL and numpy)

```
r=0                                                                         # red plane1
g=1                                                                         # green plane
b=2                                                                         # blue plane

r_search = 255
g_search = 0
b_search = 0

z = True
h = True
q = True

while q == True:

    while h == True:

        while z == True:

            coordinatestuple = np.where((data[:,:,r] == r_search) & (data[:,:,g] == g_search) & (data[:,:,b] == b_search))
            g_search = g_search + 1
            if not coordinatestuple: 
                z = False
            elif g_search == 256: 
                z = False



        coordinatestuple = np.where((data[:,:,r] == r_search) & (data[:,:,g] == g_search) & (data[:,:,b] == b_search))
        b_search = b_search + 1
        if not coordinatestuple: 
            h = False
        elif b_search == 256: 
            h = False



    coordinatestuple = np.where((data[:,:,r] == r_search) & (data[:,:,g] == g_search) & (data[:,:,b] == b_search))
    r_search = r_search - 1
    if not coordinatestuple: 
        q = False
    elif r_search == 0: 
        q = False
```

print(coordinatestuple)

Comment: Please reformat your question! It's very hard to read all jammed into one paragraph.

Comment: Have a read here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215020/2836621