# How to detect and change colours in RGB picture

Tags: python, computer-vision

Given the next picture:

```
robot = io.imread('robot.png')
```

[image]

robot will be a 1277x789x3 RGB matrix.

The question is that I want to change the orange color of the robot to purple, like this:

[image]

the problem is that I don't know how to detect the robot's orange color. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a similar problem here: [I want to change the colors in image with python from specific color range to another color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210304/i-want-to-change-the-colors-in-image-with-python-from-specific-color-range-to-an)

Following the code from link above and changing some parameters:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Load the aerial image and convert to HSV colourspace
image = cv.imread("path/image.jpg")
hsv=cv.cvtColor(image,cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Define lower and uppper limits of what we call "orange"
orange_lo=np.array([10,100,20])
orange_hi=np.array([30,255,255])

# Mask image to only select oranges
mask=cv.inRange(hsv,orange_lo,orange_hi)

# Change image to purple where we found orange
image[mask>0]=(188,0,188)

cv.imwrite("result.png",image)
```