# How to mask certain colors on an image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm working with OpenCV on this kind of an image:

[image]

I have a numpy array which contains different colors, let's say I consider this color written in BGR: `[65 71 72]` I want to get rid of this color from my image leaving it with black spaces after this color. As far as I know I have to convert my image into gray scale and then apply a mask BUT in mask I say what are lower and upper boundaries of a color, while idk what are the boundaries for this or any color, as well as what is the gray scale representation of this color. I read about many different techniques for thresholding but all examples deal with colors like `(255 0 0)`.

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215020/2836621

Answer (score 6):

You can apply `inRange` from **OpenCV** directly on the **BGR** color-space to subtract the desired color:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = np.array([ 
    [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2]], 
    [[4, 5, 6], [65 71 72], [6, 4, 5]], 
    [[7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 7], [9, 7, 8]]], dtype=np.uint8)

lower = np.array([65 71 72])
upper = np.array([65 71 72])

mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask=mask)

result = img - masked
```

Comment: sorry but I see now difference after this operation. Maybe you can try to download my image and check this method

Comment: you should investigate the code and understand it. changing it to suit you will be very little trouble.