# amplifier the red color on this image and separate it with threshold

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, colors

I would like to separate the red colour, however faint, from the rest of the image. I can't find a satisfactory method. I have used `otsu` threshold and adjusted the contrast, but so far I can't find anything satisfactory. 
I receive different images, so the colour quantity can vary more or less. It would be necessary for the program to adapt to the image received using a `threshoding` method.

Do you have an idea?

This is the code I wrote. I get the green channel to be able to separate the colours and then I amplify the different colours with `contrast_adjuster` to get a better threshold at the end. But I can't get a very good threshold.

```
green = img[..., 1]

adj_green = contrast_adjuster(green)

ret = cv2.threshold(adj_green, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[0]

mask = cv2.threshold(green, ret, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

Orange = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

Red = img - Orange

Red = cv2.cvtColor(Red, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)



def contrast_adjuster(img):
    equ = cv2.equalizeHist(img)

    return equ
```

[image]

Comment: Could you share python/opencv code that you've written? Which thresholding strategies have you tried?

Comment: try opencv `inrange` function

Comment: Have a read here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215020/2836621

Comment: @user8190410 the algorithm must adapt to the received image. The colours may vary a little and become a little darker. That's why I need to use a thresholding